# How to use ping command on script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I use PowerShell often to do automated batch patching.  I normally have to get a list of machines, ping test, take the output of that file and put it into PowerShell, move the files, and then I use `PSEXEC` to execute the bat file.  (I can't use PowerShell to remote execute, WinRM is blocked in my world).

I found a nice script for removing users from groups that pings and if there is no response, move on, but if there is, it executes the command and moves to the next.  I'm trying to adapt that for my own uses to ping, move files, and if there's no response, move on.  It looks like as of now, the script is pinging, moving, and if there's no response, it errors out with "Network Path Not Found".

My PS script is as follows:

```
#Install Cisco AnyConnect Core VPN and ISE Posture Installation
#Author: Erik R. Little
#Creation Date: 1 November 2017

#This script will do the following actions:
#1.- Get a computer list from a TXT file.
#2.- Do a ping to every computer on the list, if the computer is offline it will skip it and pass to the next one.
#3.- If the computer answers the ping it will push the AnyConnect installation files to the remote machine.
#4.- Creates a log with all the transactions.

        # Log Time Variables
        $Date = Get-Date -UFormat %b-%m-%Y
        $Hour = (Get-Date).Hour
        $Minuntes = (Get-Date).Minute
        $Log = "C:\support\cisco\Log Files\AnyConnect Install-" + $Date + "-" + $Hour + "-" + $Minuntes + ".log"

        #Creates a log file for this process.
        Start-Transcript -Path $Log  -Force 

        #List of computers to be check
        $ComputerNames = Get-Content "C:\support\cisco\Computers.txt"

        #Ping the computers on the list
        foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {
            if (-not (Test-Connection $ComputerName -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction Continue)) {
                #If theres no ping answer pass to the next one
                Write-Output "Computer $ComputerName not reachable (PING) - Skipping this computer..."
            } else {
                #If computer does answer the ping
                Write-Output "Computer $ComputerName is online"
            }
        }

        foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {
            Write-Host $ComputerName
            if ((Test-Path "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco") -eq 0) {
                mkdir "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
                robocopy /mir "C:\support\cisco" "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
            } elseif ((Test-Path "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco") -eq 1) {
                robocopy /mir "C:\support\cisco" "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
            }
        }
    }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

So to sum up:  I want the script to ping and move on if there's no response, but if there is a ping, move the file, and then move to the next.

Comment: If condition with ping status will do the work. Google a little bit on that . Show what have you tried with the code

Comment: Have you tried `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`?

Comment: The code you posted should fail with a syntax error because it has 2 spurious closing curly brackets.

Comment: `Test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Answer (score 4):

Using a single `foreach`.

I've also updated your logic for `Test-Connection` and `Test-path` so the code is cleaner.

```
#Creates a log file for this process.
Start-Transcript -Path $Log  -Force 

#List of computers to be check
$ComputerNames = Get-Content "C:\support\cisco\Computers.txt"

foreach ($ComputerName in $ComputerNames) {
    if (Test-Connection $ComputerName -Quiet -Count 1 -ErrorAction Continue ) {
        Write-Output "Computer $ComputerName is online" 

        if (Test-path "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco") {
            robocopy /mir "C:\support\cisco" "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
        }
        else {
            mkdir "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
            robocopy /mir "C:\support\cisco" "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco"
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-Output "Computer $ComputerName not reachable (PING) - Skipping this computer..."
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

---

**EDIT:**

Removing all duplicate code and values would give you even more concise `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($Computer in $ComputerNames) {
    $source = "C:\support\cisco"
    $destination = "\\$Computer\c$\support\cisco"

    if (Test-Connection $Computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
        Write-Output "Computer $Computer is online" 
        if (-not (Test-path $destination)) {New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory}
        robocopy /mir $source $destination
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Computer $Computer not reachable (PING) - Skipping this computer..."
    }
}
```

Comment: I would also change it to `if (-not (Test-path "\\$ComputerName\c$\support\cisco")){mkdir...} robocopy...` instead of having the same code in each condition block which is redundant.

Comment: This worked, and my life is a thousand times easier.  Thank you!

Comment: @ErikRossLittle Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: It can even be shorter like this `New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction Ignore` depending on the PowerShell version.